# How to convert bytes string to bytes

Tags: python, byte

I have a string from a database request as follows:

```
result = "b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07\x80\x00\x03'"
type(result) -> <class 'str'>
```

How do I convert it to bytes? It should be like this:

```
a = b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07\x80\x00\x03'

type(a) -> <class 'bytes'>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From what I understood (I have a terrible understanding of english):
You can use the `eval()` or the `exec()` function to convert a string to any Python object you want.
Here's an example:

```
a = "b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07\x80\x00\x03'"
x = eval(a.encode("unicode-escape").decode())
print(type(x)) -> bytes
```

Same thing for the `exec` function.

Comment: This will result in a ValueError exception

Comment: Thank you for making me notice that. I just found a more complicated but correct way: `a = "b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07\x80\x00\x03'"
x = eval(a.encode("unicode-escape").decode())
print(x)`. It automatically escapes all characters and than evaluates it. I tried this method and it worked.

Comment: This solution worked perfectly for me without any troubles!

Comment: Use [ast.literal_eval](https://python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) e.g. `ast.literal_eval(a.encode("unicode-escape").decode())`

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `eval()` function unless you truth the input like [greenegran0 answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75571560/how-to-convert-bytes-string-to-bytes/75571622#75571622), because it can make your code insecure.

You can use `bytes()` class or `encode()` function to convert it into bytes instead.

```
result = "b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07\x80\x00\x03'"
result = bytes(result[2:-1], "latin1") # result[2:-1] remove b'' at the beginning and end
#Or: result = result[2:-1].encode("latin1")

print(type(result)) # Return <class 'bytes'>
```